# Error when adding edges to network graph: 'v_of_edge' for a cleaned list entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, social-networking

I have a cleaned list.
Like ['42,1', '42,2', '42,18']
I skip the rest cause its very long.
When I try to use add_edge in networkx. It comes up the error

```
add_edge() missing 1 required positional argument: 'v_of_edge'
```

Here is my code.

```
for i in cleanedList:
  G.add_edge(i)
```

I believe i in cleanedList is already as a form 42,1. So I try to directly pass it into add_edge. How could this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

You still need to split your string at `,` I guess into start node `u` and end node `v` (as stated in [`add_edge`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.add_edge.html)

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

cleaned_list = ['42,1', '42,2', '42,18']

for i in cleaned_list:
    G.add_edge(*i.split(","))

print(G.edges())
# [('42', '1'), ('42', '2'), ('42', '18')]
```